# How to deal with List of controls in C#

Tags: c#, memory, destructor

I have a List of controls i.e. list inside my custom Form. When I add some control to the Form, at the same time I add that same control to the list. Should I clean the list and when? On Dispose? Otherwise, my controls will not be destroyed? (I am a C++ guy)

Comment: Why don't you just use `Controls` property of form? It is actually that you want - collection of controls owned by form. Any reason to maintain another one list?

Comment: It is impossible to provide a certain answer to this question without more specifics. But: it doesn't matter where else you store reference to these `Control` instances; as long as they are descendants of the `Form` itself (i.e. contained by the `Form` as user-interface elements, either directly or indirectly), they'll be disposed when the `Form` instance is.

Comment: I don't want to iterate over controls to find my controls.
And each control has an event handler attached to an object that is also used somewhere else. I'm concerned for memory leaks.

Comment: External, have you looked into data binding? I wouldn't worry about memory leaks until you start dealing with idisposables

Answer (score 1):

If the list's only reference resides inside the `Form` itself, then you don't need to clear the `List`. When the Form is garbage collected, List will also be collected(also the controls in the list).

If you have the reference to that List outside the Form in the question, then yes you need to `Clear` the List, otherwise the controls in the list will not be collected till the `List` itself is collected.

Also note that controls in the List will be disposed as soon as the Form is Disposed(given that same references to control is added in Form). But Dispose and Garbage Collection are two different things.

Comment: The list is not referenced but created. Controls can be destroyed and still exist as references in the list?

Comment: @External Yes Form's Dispose will dispose all the controls in it, it doesn't care where and all it is referenced. You can try it yourself.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel your answer was completely right but this comment of yours seems misleading. As you mentioned in the answer, objects won't get garbage collected if they have any references outside the Form, event if they get `Dispose`d.

Comment: @Alireza I don't think any of that is misleading. Both are correct. Objects will not be GC'd but they will be disposed, because Form.Dispose will dispose them, note that OP said that he has added the same control to the Form and also to a List. So it will be disposed, but not GC'd if there are outstanding references available. Correct me if I'm wrong..

Comment: Of course it is correct. I just meant your comment could be improved that's what you did in the next one. I'm on your side ;)

Comment: should I clear the list on form dispose?

Comment: We can't answer any further without looking to your code. It will be dangerous to do so. We may assume something, but that may not be the case. So please post some code to ask specific question. We need to know where and all you refer that list, how you populate it etc.

Answer (score 0):

The Form will Dispose the controls only if the controls are added in the Form's Controls collection (i.e. if they are part of the control tree). If you simply have controls as members of the Form class which are not part of the Control tree they will not be disposed. Of course without a code sample it is impossible to tell which one is your case. Also note that Dispose has nothing to do with event handlers and you can have memory leaks (or more precisely object leaks) even if Dispose is called.